# Hide back button on iOS 11.2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to hide the back button of the Navigation Bar. 
I can do that in all iOS versions older than iOS 11.2.2

I've already tried the following code:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
 self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
 self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Nothing seems to work in iOS 11.2.2

I'm using Xcode 9 and Swift 4

Comment: you are using xcode 9.2?

Comment: @khawar-islam yes I am using xCode 9.2

Comment: you want to hide from all controller or an specific controller?

Comment: @khawar-islam I am trying to hide from a specific controller, but in this case hiding from all controllers works too

Comment: check the code, i testing on my xcode it work fine

Answer (score 5):

I am using Xcode9, Swift 4 & iOS 11.2 and

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

works completely fine.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 Xcode 9.2**

Suggest that I am moving From A controller to B Controller and i embed navigation controller before A. In controller B i write this code and its work fine.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its worked for me.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
  if segue.identifier == "viewcontroller"{
    let objVC = segue.destination as? viewcontroller
    objVC?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the `hidesBackButton` attribute before present, or push hided back button view controller.

```
@objc func showHidedBackButtonViewController() {
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let hidedBackButtonViewController = HidedBackButtonViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(hidedBackButtonViewController, animated: true)
}
```